# Does attack progression go over the attack speed cap?

Tags: smite

many gods have an attack progression that changes their attack speed.

Kali for example has an attack progression of 1/.5/.5 where the last 2 hits have double attack speed but hit for half damage.

the attack speed cap is 2.5x. Do god's progression system affect this?

Comment: I would think almost certainly attack progressions are not taken into account for the attack speed cap. Otherwise, your cap would effectively be 1.25x for many physical gods, and you can get that with a single item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that reddit is the final answer on anything, but there are several people in agreement that attack progressions are [not hindered by the attack speed cap](http://www.reddit.com/r/Smite/comments/23upmn/how_attack_progression_work_related_to_attack/).

Comment: For smite, Reddit really is the final answer.

Comment: @CrabtasticGoat Citation needed.

Comment: For Smite questions, Reddit really is the final answer. Moderators working at Hi-Rez look at posts made there.